# Xamarin forms maps cannot load assembly

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just added the Xamarin.Forms.Maps nuget package to my project and added this code on my main page to create a map:

```
 var map = new Map(
        MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        Content = stack;
```

Everything seems fine however when I try to compile it I get this error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.

Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

**Question**: Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix this?

Comment: some info: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @JohnB so your saying the problem is that i have not setup google play services?

Comment: it could be - have you?

Comment: @JohnB not sure I just looked up the build.gradle thing for xamarin forms and it says that it is not really used as nuget packages are use in the place of that and I have installed the nuget packages so everything should be good.

Comment: oh - did not know that - sorry just suggesting

Comment: Nah its all good thanks for the idea.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96275/could-not-load-assembly-xamarin-googleplayservices-maps)?